How do I fix powershell input error on vscode?
I am new to the world of coding and am not super duper technical. I will try to be as thorough as possible. I am doing a AWS course and am saving some scripts to a github repo that I am using Project IDX to update. I installed Powershell in the nix file and am able to open it in vscode but for some reason everytime I type something it begins adding additional letters and is not following my input at all.
For example if I wanted to write the word clear, this is what would appear: cclclecleaclear
I installed the Powershell Vscode extension in hopes that its configurations would fix it and unfortunately no luck. The nix package installer has it running 7.4.0.
Keep in mind:
-All other shells are working fine
-Keyboard is working fine
Please let me know if anybody has any suggestions or potentially even came across this. Thanks!
I already tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the environment and still no luck.

where you write nix, you probably do mean unix or linux? When so, you better ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/  ( Because this seem to be more an OS related question, then a programming question )

Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. also add the output of the version printing command of your shell
